# Should I always write extra configuration in Deployment Descriptor everytime I create a servlet in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

In eclipse, everytime new servlet is created, it will not be automatically registered in web.xml. But why is that so ? I mean, from what I have read, DD is very efficient, for example, when we ever want to change something in our web app, like changing url pattern of servlet, we don't have to find the class, the container will handle it by its own. Should i register every servlet that i create in DD ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes every servlet needs to be registered and mapped. Nowadays you can also do it via the @Servlet annotation.